# Adding new field to feature class?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, esri-geodatabase, fields-attributes, geometric-network

I'm using one of the esri model sewer system geodatabases. It includes empty feature classes and a geometric network.  i need to add a field to one of the pre-made feature classes, but it won't let me. I've tried adding it in ArcGIS Pro, ArcGIS Desktop and in ArcCatalog, but all of them won't let me update or add any fields.

Answer (score 1):

I just needed an Advanced or Standard License, then I was able to add the field!